# Walking In-front of Someone Davening Shemona Esrei

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, shemoneh-esrei

1. I read somewhere that *shtenders, chairs, tables* and *benches* aren’t considered an interruption between the one *davening* and one passing before him unless the shtender is 10 טפחים tall by 4 טפחים wide. Where is the halachic source for this?
2. I also read that even if there is an interposition of 10 טפחים and 4 טפחים wide one should be strict not to pass before someone *davening*. Where is the halachic source for this?

Comment: If a chair is not an interposition, and you're davening right in front of someone else, what keeps you from violating this prohibition?  If sitting is prohibited, what does the person who cannot stand long (because of disability) have to do if the fellow standing behind his seat davens long?

Comment: See [Walking in front of someone *Davening*](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Shemona_Esreh)

Comment: @BruceJames My rebbe in yeshiva taught that if you are davening in front of somebody, you should not take your 3 steps back at the end of davening until the person behind you has finished unless you are able to take the three steps to the side and not in front of that other person. In the case of a person with disability, that is obviously an extenuating circumstance if he is unable to move to a different position.