# Do we still need 4 amot for davening with benches?

Tags: halacha, tefilla

Most shuls nowadays separate rows with benches/chairs and shtenders. If this is the case, must someone avoid walking in front of someone davening, even separated by benches? It seems less likely to disturb then, and harder to bump into them.

FWIW, 4 amot is generally considered 6-8 feet. This means, in my shul, one would have to walk 3 rows in front of someone to be out of their 4 amot.

Comment: Possibly related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/43654/walking-in-front-of-someone-davening-shemona-esrei

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/19008/when-youre-trapped-by-someone-davening-behind-you

Answer (score 1):

[Halachipedia](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Shemona_Esreh#cite_note-32) says

> It’s forbidden to walk in front of someone praying within 4 Amot.
>
> Even an interposition of 10 Tefachim and 4 Tefachim wide one should be
>   strict not to pass before someone Davening. However if the
>   interruption is taller than the one Davening, then it’s permissible to
>   walk in front of the one Davening. [32]
>
> A shtender isn’t considered an interruption between the one Davening
>   and one passing before him unless the Shtender is 10 Tefachim tall by
>   4 Tefachim wide. [33]
>
> [32]  Mishna Brurah 102:2 writes that one may not pass before someone
>   even if there’s an interruption of ten Tefachim with the width of 4
>   Tefachim since it still can ruin the kavana of the one Davening.
>   Therefore, if it’s as tall as the one Davening it won’t ruin his
>   kavana and it’s permissible.
>
> [33] Halichot Shlomo 8:33 in the note based on Mishna Brurah 102:2

The halacha in [33] seems to depend on the dimensions of the interposition; there should be no difference based on the nature of interposition (bench/chair or shtender).