# Walking in front of a person Davening Shemoneh Esrei

Tags: tefilla, shemoneh-esrei

I heard somewhere that you're not allowed to walk, stand, or sit, anywhere within 4 Amos of a person Davening Shemoneh Esrei because you're walking through the Shechinah.

Does this have a source? Are there any exceptions to the rule? Say there's a table in between you and the person? What if you're in a rush, and there's no way to get by unless you pass through their 4 Amos?

Comment: partial dupe http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/44531/759

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/19008/759

Comment: From [here](https://powerofspeech.org/daily-companion/split-personalities) 
A story about Rabbi Moshe Feinstein: Once, R’ Moshe was on his way to an important meeting when he noticed someone near the doorway praying Shemoneh Esrei. He stopped in his tracks and would go no further. “There is a wall blocking my path,” R’ Moshe explained. The wall, of course, was the strength of the halachah which prohibited him from walking any further.